# How to change format of date value of date columns in CSV file without changing other columns' value?

Tags: python, csv, file, date, type-conversion

Currently, I need to work with Python to process CSV files. More specifically, I need to convert the date value from the format "mm/dd/yyyy" in columns which have date values to the format "yyyy-mm-dd" in each row in the file and not change the values of other columns. After the transformation, the result will be written in the new file (including the converted columns and non-converted columns).

Note that we cannot know exactly how many date columns in the file need to be transformed and which columns have date values.

For example, if I have a file `test.csv` like

```
name, dob, gender, joindate
John, 10/21/2000, 1, 09/25/2022
Hannah, 12/31/1980, 2, 09/25/2022
Tom, 02/09/1999, 1, 09/25/2022
Alice, 02/05/1999, 2, 09/21/2022
```

After transformation, the results will be written to `result.csv` and it will be like

```
name, dob, gender, joindate
John, 2000-10-21, 1, 2022-09-25
Hannah, 1980-12-31, 2, 2022-09-25
Tom, 1999-02-09, 1, 2022-09-25
Alice, 1999-02-05, 2, 2022-09-21
```

I've written the code to transform the file

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
with open('test.csv', 'r') as source:
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        source.readline()
        for row in reader:
            ts = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d") #strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")
            print(ts)
            row[0]=ts
            if ts != "":
                writer.writerow(row)
source.close()
result.close()
```

However, although the code can convert the format as I expect and write the result to a new file successfully, it still has some limits:

1. The input file must have the first column has the date value, which has the format mm/dd/yyyy. Otherwise, the code will be failed. It's not flexible.
2. If the files have other date columns, the code cannot convert their value to the right format, because it only recognized the first column.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding column numbers (`row[0]`), iterate over the columns (`for col_num in range(len(row)):`) and `try` the `strptime`. If there's a `ValueError` `continue` to the next column, otherwise store the conversion in the row at the column index (`row[col_num] = ts`).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over rows in file and then iterate over columns in row using  `enumerate` to get an index number as well as the column value. Use Python regex module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) to identify if column has `mm/dd/yyyy` formatted  value and if so use `datetime` to change to `yyyy-mm-dd` format. See notes below the code.

```
cat test.csv                                                                                                                                                             
name, dob, gender, joindate
John, 10/21/2000, 1, 09/25/2022
Hannah, 12/31/1980, 2, 09/25/2022
Tom, 02/09/1999, 1, 09/25/2022
Alice, 02/05/1999, 2, 09/21/2022


import re
import csv
from datetime import datetime

date_reg_exp = re.compile('[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}') 

with open('test.csv') as source:
     with open('result.csv', 'w') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result)
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            for idx, col in enumerate(row):
                if date_reg_exp.match(col.strip()):
                    row[idx] = datetime.strptime(row[idx].strip(), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            writer.writerow(row)

cat result.csv                                                                                                                                                           
John,2000-10-21, 1,2022-09-25
Hannah,1980-12-31, 2,2022-09-25
Tom,1999-02-09, 1,2022-09-25
Alice,1999-02-05, 2,2022-09-21
```

Some notes:

1. No point in using `lineterminator` as from here [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)

> Dialect.lineterminator

> The string used to terminate lines produced by the writer. It defaults to '\r\n'.

> Note

> The reader is hard-coded to recognise either '\r' or '\n' as end-of-line, and ignores lineterminator. This behavior may change in the future.

2. Does the CSV file really have a space between the comma and the next value? This introduces an empty space character that you have to deal e.g. `col.strip()`. Life would be simpler without the spaces.
3. `source.close()` and `result.close()` are redundant. The `with` context manager will automatically close the files.